# Nginx: can I use $server_name when specifying access log location?

Tags: configuration, nginx, webserver, access-log

I want to write a config file for an nginx virtual host that looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-domain-name.com;

    access_log /home/me/sites/$server_name/logs/access.log;
    error_log  /home/me/sites/$server_name/logs/error.log;

    location /static {
        alias /home/me/sites/$server_name/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

Using `$server_name` seems to work find for the `location /static`, but it doesn't seem to work for the `access_log` and `error_log` -- am I doing something wrong?  Or is this just not possible?  Can I do it some other way?

[update] - this is the error message when trying to reload nginx:

`nginx: [emerg] open() "/home/me/sites/$server_name/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Comment: [Outlook not good](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2011-September/029278.html).

Comment: You need to use the $host variable #http://serverfault.com/a/283182

Comment: The host variable can't be used here, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wanted to do this too, but apparently by design nginx cannot expand variables in the `error_log` command, in case there are errors doing so and it cannot get a log filename to write them to.

Their suggestion is to use some program to generate your configuration files instead.  You could use `sed` for this, to automatically search-and-replace your own variables and placing the output in the nginx configuration directory.

Comment: right. In the end I just figured I'd use `sed` to subsitute in the hostname in multiple places, and never mind the repetition...